# Selenium writing on two different text boxes for the same sendKeys()

Tags: selenium, automation

I have an issue where selenium sendKeys(String) method, writes half the string on a text box, then complete the rest of the string in a different text box.

I don't know how is this possible, I think it might be an issue with the selenium driver itself (am using chrome driver 2.13). Any idea about a root cause for this.Note that the code worked fine for a long time.

regards

Comment: Too little information. Possible reason could be that both text boxes have same locators?

Comment: First of all if you can change the code then rename the text box id, secondly if you can't change the code just try to use sendKeys in a enclosed manner, stop the execution after the string with ; at the end

Comment: Both ids are completely different, and the issue happens only sometimes, this is why i have so little information, because the issue is very random.